# How to make Ubuntu 20.04 start without GDM and in multiuser shell mode with startx starting all normal session services such as the dock?

Tags: 20.04, xorg

I'd like to start up Ubuntu 20.04 to a textual user login and shell like Server and then when using the system be able to start X for the user by just executing `startx` such that when you start it, the feature parity is essentially one-for-one with normal system usage (such as having the "dock" or app favorites that lives on the side).

I'm able to accomplish most of this with the following:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user
sudo reboot
```

At this point I can login with multi-user mode and execute `startx` to get a fairly vanilla session, but there's no dock (or whatever Gnome calls the side / favorites bar).

How can one control which services start that are necessary to have mostly a normal system starting with `startx`?

Answer (score 1):

Gnome Tweaks is the solution:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

[image: Tweaks]

Appearance settings are available in here in addition to enabling the Ubuntu extension(s):
[image]